# Выравнивание текста по центру и слева в bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap

Всем доброго дня.
Верстаю footer с помощью bootstrap. И не могу никак догнать, как сделать, чтобы текст был выровнен по центру div, а по строчкам выровнен слева.
Как выглядит сейчас.
В интернете и в поиске не нашел.
[image: Что получается сейчас]

```html
<!-- Подвал -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-black">
      <footer class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3">
        <p class="col-md-3 mb-0 text-center">&copy; 2022 Название компании</p>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-0">
          <h5>Адрес</h5>
          <p>г. Москва</p>
          <p>Улица ******</p>
          <p>вход Ё</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-0">
          <h5>Контакты</h5>
          <p>+7-495-555-5555</p>
          <p>info@******.ru</p>
        </div>
    
        <ul class="nav col-md-3 flex-column">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 ">Behance</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 ">LinkedIn</a></li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <!-- Подвал -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось сделать так.

```html
<!-- Подвал -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-black">
      <div class="container-xxl">
        <footer class="row align-items-center py-4">
          <div class="col-md-3 text-md-center mb-md-0 mb-3">
            <p class="mb-0">&copy; 2022 Название компании</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-3">
            <h6 class="fw-bold mb-1">Адрес</h6>
            <p class="mb-0">г. Москва</p>
            <p class="mb-0">Улица ******</p>
            <p class="mb-0">вход Ё</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 mx-auto mb-md-0 mb-3">
            <h6 class="fw-bold mb-1">Контакты</h6>
            <p class="mb-0">+7-495-555-5555</p>
            <p class="mb-0">info@******.ru</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2 text-md-center">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 py-1">Behance</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-0 py-1">LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </footer>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Подвал -->
```